# Cannot create and grant role to user in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-roles, user-management, role-manager

The project is ASP.NET Core MVC, .NET 6. I'm trying to seed a role if it's not there yet and create a user that will have this role. I tried every way to twist the code and it doesn't work. When I run the app for the first time, the following error appears on the line where the user is added to the role:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "ViewMovies", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

Then when I check the database the new role is created, but the user is not.

This all happens in Program.cs. Here I create scope and use it to get role manager and user manager. Then, if the role does not exist, create it and a new user. After that add the new role to the new user.

```
var app = builder.Build();
var scope = app.Services
                .GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                ?.CreateScope();

if (scope is not null)
{
    using (scope)
    {
        var roleManager = scope
            .ServiceProvider
            .GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = scope
            .ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        
        Task
        .Run(async () =>
        {
            if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("test"))
            {
                return;
            }

            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "test" };
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

            const string testEmail = "test@role.com";
            const string testPassword = "test123";
            var user = new User
            {
                Email = testEmail,
                UserName = testEmail
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync(user, testPassword);
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        })
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
    }
}
```

I have registered these services:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ViewMoviesDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the data I was creating for the new user. The password was not valid according to the password restrictions that were set in the services. The password `test123` does not contain capital letters and non-alphanumeric characters, which are required by default. Changing it to `Test123+` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error it seems that You are trying to create a user with the same Id, Email etc.. which causes user to be the instance of the same user. Role adding on the same user cause the error because the user has already had the role. You should try to create user with different email.

In Identity server database it uses email to uniquely identify the users. Try
clearing the users table data if possible along with roles. If above did not work.

Comment: The mock user data I set is unique to those in the database. There is no other user with this email or username.

Comment: What about Id? Can you check the roles table for existing userId ?@FadoBagi

Comment: The AspNetRoles table has the _test_ role created. But there is no new data in either AspNetUser or AspNetUserRoles.

Comment: I assume that creating a user this way creates a unique ID for them.

Comment: Yes can you try switching the last two lines `await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name); await userManager.CreateAsync(user, testPassword);`

Comment: Everything remains the same after changing the two lines.

Comment: Basically, it is violating of Foreign key constraint between AspNetUserRoles and AspNetUsers_UserId. It hard to tell looking in at high-level. better if you can share the classes and tables snap shot of each table

Comment: The tables are default. I have not touched anything related to id.